# How to Zoom in or Zoom out a JtextArea in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Im doing a notepad with java and im trying to implement a zoom in/out to a JTextarea content.

For now what I have done is increase or decrease the font of the text to achieve the zoom effect. But what I want is to zoom the JTextArea component.

I know there are classes like Graphics and Graphics2D and methods like paint or paintcomponent but i have no idea how to use them.

I want to zoom from the JMenuItem button that I created.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why?  Are you designing new fonts?

Comment: Im doing a project for my programming class. Im trying to make windows notepad.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536503/how-do-i-zoom-on-swing-components-using-affinetransform